# Is there any way to set threshold value for brakeman warning in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, brakeman

I have integrated `brakeman` with `jenkins`. There are lots of warnings and currently I want to skip them all. Build should fail when count goes beyond the `threshold` value. Currently I am not much familiar with `Jenkins` and the `brakeman`. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Brakeman post-build action, click the "advanced" button:

[image: Post Build Action Advanced Button]

The advanced settings allow setting a number of thresholds:

[image: Brakeman Post Build Action Advanced Settings]

If you check "compute new warnings", you get options to base build status off of the change in warnings rather than absolute numbers:

[image]